# How to return UIMA Ruta's output from a server?

Tags: java, ruta

I want to run Ruta scripts on a separate server and return the output for further processing (in Java).

The only way that I know to trigger a Ruta script is by calling the ***engine.process(cas)*** method from a Java maven project. But it doesn't generate an xmi file which could be sent back to the client (i.e., Java server) for further processing. Neither can I return the CAS object to the client (if I'm right).

How can I achieve it?

- How to return CAS from server to client?
  (OR)
- How to generate xmi file while running Ruta from Java code ?

Tell me a better way if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a comment to the second bullit point in your question:

In the java code when running `engine.process()`, you could simply use the [CasIOUtils](https://uima.apache.org/d/uima-as-2.9.0/apidocs/org/apache/uima/util/CasIOUtils.html) to write the CAS to some (file/byte) outputstream in the XMI format or in some other format.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks ! FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
XmiCasSerializer.serialize(cas, fileOutputStream); ==> worked !

Comment: But please let me know of the best way to take Ruta process alone on a separate server. I want to run Java(on Server1), Ruta(Server2) and Java(Server1) again.

Comment: Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653768/xcasparsingexception-while-trying-to-deserialize-xmi-into-cas-object