# XCASParsingException while trying to deserialize xmi into CAS object

Tags: java, ruta

I have made Ruta scripts run from Java and have converted the resulting CAS object into an xmi file as below;

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputXmiFile);
XmiCasSerializer.serialize(cas, fileOutputStream);
```

When I try to convert it back into a CAS object (on another server), as below;

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(xmiFile);
XmlCasDeserializer.deserialize(fileInputStream, cas);
```

I get the below **exception**;

```
XCASParsingException: Error parsing XCAS or XMI-CAS from source <unknown> at line <unknown>, column <unknown>: unknown type: NULL.
```

*A snapshot of the exception.*[image]

Comment: Did you check if the types system used to create the CAS on another server is compatible/equivalent?

Comment: It looks like you are using the XCas format instead of the XMI format. You could give CasIOUtil a try.

Comment: Tried 
  - CasIOUtil.writeXmi(cas1, outputXmiFile);
  - CasIOUtil.readXmi(cas, outputXmiFile);
respectively and getting a similar exception while reading;
java.io.IOException: Error parsing XCAS or XMI-CAS from source <unknown> at line 1, column 1415: unknown type: NULL.

Comment: Can you please gimme the exact code snippet to convert from CAS to .xmi file and .xmi to CAS object?

Comment: Also plz let me know if there would be any size difference between the xmi generated in the Ruta workbench and the one which is generated from CAS object ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya Thanks ! It worked !

`import org.apache.uima.util.CasIOUtils;`

**CAS to XMI**

```
CasIOUtils.save(cas, fileOutputStream, SerialFormat.XMI);
```

**XMI to CAS**

```
CasIOUtils.load(fileInputStream, cas);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when there's really something wrong with your XMI file.

Tip:
Another way of opening XMI files might be by using [XmiReader](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.12.0/docs/format-reference.html#format-org.dkpro.core.io.xmi.XmiReader).

```
File xmlFile = new File("/path/to/file.xmi");
CollectionReaderDescription description = createReaderDescription(
   XmiReader.class,
   XmiReader.PARAM_SOURCE_LOCATION, xmlFile
);
```